# Can I track the use of ConfigurationManager settings

Tags: c#, .net, settings, config, appsettings

I am trying to clean up the web.config in multiple projects, but am worried that I may remove an appsetting/connectionstring that is being used somewhere.

For example, I want to know if `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MySetting"])` is used.

I can of course do a global find for ConfigurationManager or Appsettings, but that doesn't check in compiled dlls (this project has some dlls referenced that i know are looking for certain keys).

I would love to be able to 'log' (text file, db, anywhere) the use of the .config file, minimally logging the key name, but ideally the namespace/method that called it.  If this is possible, I could come back in some amount of time and check the log to see what is used.

Deleting the settings and seeing if the app throws an exception is tempting :), but not a realistic option.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to use aspect to log that a method was called.
I'm not sure if you will be able to get which configuration or key was retrieved but having all the places that's called is already a starting point.

Hope that helps.

Give a try for [PostSharp](https://www.postsharp.net/aop.net) or [Unity](http://weblogs.asp.net/ricardoperes/unity-part-3-aspect-oriented-programming).